slice amount into ranges according to ranges from table
anyway to slice amount into ranges according to ranges from table as below
------------------------------------------
| ID  | CAT_ID | START_RANGE | END_RANGE |
------------------------------------------
| 1   | 1      | 279         | 450       |
| 2   | 1      | 451         | 650       |
| 3   | 1      | 651         | 850       |
| 4   | 1      | 851         | 1100      |
| 5   | 1      | 1101        | 3000      |
------------------------------------------

i write this query but it will not get ranges dynamiclly from table above any ideas
SELECT CASE WHEN (SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE) > (ALTA + 279) THEN 
            CASE WHEN ((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE)          > (ALTA + 1100)) THEN ((CEIL((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE - ALTA - 1100) * 15/100))) 
                ELSE CASE WHEN ((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE) > (ALTA + 850))  THEN ((CEIL((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE - ALTA - 850)  * 13/100))) 
                ELSE CASE WHEN ((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE) > (ALTA + 650))  THEN ((CEIL((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE - ALTA - 650)  * 11/100))) 
                ELSE CASE WHEN ((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE) > (ALTA + 450))  THEN ((CEIL((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE - ALTA - 450)  * 9/100)))
                ELSE CASE WHEN ((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE) > (ALTA + 279))  THEN ((CEIL((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE - ALTA - 279)  * 7/100)))
                ELSE CASE WHEN ((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE) > (ALTA + 279))  THEN ((CEIL((SAL_AMOUNT + ALLOWANCE - ALTA - 279)  * 0/100)))
       END END END END END END END AS "ER"
  FROM TABLE_NAME
     WHERE TABLE_NAME.ID = 61237;


Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with your sample data as CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for ALL the relevant tables. At the moment your code is selecting from a table and using the ID, SAL_AMOUNT, ALLOWANCE and ALTA columns but your sample data does not have any of those columns. Do you have two tables or just one?

You appear to want to use a JOIN:
SELECT t.*,
       r.*,
       CEIL(t.SAL_AMOUNT + t.ALLOWANCE - t.ALTA - r.start_range) * (r.id * 2 + 5)/100
         AS ER
FROM   TABLE_NAME t
       INNER JOIN range_table r
       ON t.sal_amount + t.allowance - t.alta BETWEEN r.start_range AND r.end_range
WHERE  t.ID = 61237;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE range_table (id, cat_id, start_range, end_range ) AS
  SELECT 1, 1,  279,  450 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1,  451,  650 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1,  651,  850 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1,  851, 1100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 1, 1101, 3000 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_name (id, sal_amount, allowance, alta) AS
  SELECT 61237,  300, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 61237,  600, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 61237,  800, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 61237, 1000, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 61237, 2000, 0, 0 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
SAL_AMOUNT
ALLOWANCE
ALTA
ID
CAT_ID
START_RANGE
END_RANGE
ER




61237
2000
0
0
5
1
1101
3000
134.85


61237
1000
0
0
4
1
851
1100
19.37


61237
800
0
0
3
1
651
850
16.39


61237
600
0
0
2
1
451
650
13.41


61237
300
0
0
1
1
279
450
1.47



fiddle
